# How to make deep intersections work in typescript after 4.9?

Tags: typescript, types

The following intersection used to work in typescript, but after 4.9 is no longer does:

```
type G = { props: (
  { a: { foo: 1 }}
  & { a: { bar: 2 }}
)} & { props: { a: { qux: 3}}}

const g: G = {
  props: {
    a: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2,
      qux: 3,  // only in works in 4.8 and older
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA4lC8UDeUwCcD2YDOAuKAFAFBTJQCG+KAZhhvgIxQC+zJUAZGZWQEblp8AJhZsAlM05l0WPNypQAjgFcAHvgDMrNkQDGGAHbZgUAOb44iJOxk4q7Uj2ukXUWvSgMANA5f9BUEI+rqQq6lAaXqQA9NFQhgA2IFAA7hhoANbYUACWBlAALAB0ABwUBgAm8QkVEGi+bKRszEA)

I put in [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52397), but suspect it was intentional and will not be changed.

Anyways, **How are we supposed to do it now?** A special utility type?

Comment: Seems like a bug tbh... Anyways I found that if you condense the intersections into a single type it will work: https://tsplay.dev/w2p7rm

Comment: Yeah, it seems to actually be a bug.  Every issue I've ever found has been a feature so far, so I figured it was the same case.

Thanks for the fix, I guess this bug will go away eventually though.